# Puzzling return values on Java's List

Tags: java

I'm puzzled by the return values on Java's Lists.

I would have expected operations such as `add` and `remove` to return the index of the added or removed element, instead they just return true on success.

While with `add` I may get this id calling `size`-1 (guess it's not expensive), with `remove` I have to call `indexOf`, which looks like a waste to me.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps list is not the data structure you need - an example of why this is awkward would help.

Comment: After removal, the item isn't in the list, so an index doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Emma: true, it is not, but I'm editing foreign code and this looks like the least disruptive modification I can do in this situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the explanation is that [add](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29) and [remove](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) are on the [Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface, so they apply to <strike>Map</strike> Set as well as List based data structures.

Comment: Or your implementation of `List` may be a sorted list.

Comment: Beat me to it, so I'll remove my answer.  To elaborate, Maps and Sets, in general, have no concept of ordering or "index".

Comment: The [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Map.html) interface does not extend `Collection` and does not have an add method.

Answer (score 3):

What about adding and removig using index

Comment: yes, use indexOf(Object obj) to get the index then call remove(int i). Now you have the index. If you use an ArrayList this will not be inefficient.